# Renewal of expiring b1/b2 visa. Expired f1 visa is the most recent one. How do I fill in DS 160?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, visa-renewals

I have a **B1/B2 10 years long valid visa** that is expiring this week. I want to **renew** it.
I had an **F1 visa** for a few years **in between** these 10yrs that is now **expired**. What do I write in the **DS-160 form for renewal** of B1/B2 in the column for the '****most recent visa**'?** If I put the **expired F1 visa details**, it then asks "**do you want to renew the same category visa**?" and I have to say **NO**.
There is no place to give 
details of the old B1/B2 visa that I actually want to renew.

And also my B1/B2 visa is on a, now, expired, old passport!

Comment: Thanks Marcel P. But this would be a visa renewal without an interview.

Answer (score 2):

Your most recent visa is the F1 so you should mention that. The Visa officer will already have the information about your old B2 Visa when conducting your interview.

Comment: Thanks Marcel P. But this would be a visa renewal without an interview.

Comment: @Rashmi The answer would be the same regardless.